# How to add a new line in HTML when using flex?

Tags: html, css, spacing, margins

I want separate messages to have some vertical distance in between them. Every message is a span and here is the CSS code that I wrote for spans:

```
span {
        color: #eeeeee;
        float: right;
        font-size: 120%;
        margin-right: 6%;
        margin-left: 30%;
        background-color: #393e46;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 5px 25px;
        padding: 10px 18px 10px 20px;
        margin-top: 2%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
```

And here is the code for 2 messages next to each other:

```
<span style="padding: 10px 20px 10px 18px;">hey</span>
<br>
<span style="float: left; margin-left: 6%; margin-right: 30%; border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 5px; background-color: rgb(104, 109, 117); padding: 10px 20px 10px 18px;">Hi!</span>
```

And here is the result:

[image: result]

I forgot to say that this is an issue for short messages (less than 4 characters long). Is there any way to fix this? I tried using `div` instead of span and I had the same issue there. I tried tweaking `margin` but it worked not good enough to use it (long messages look bad with those margins and the whole code starts to get messy and I don't want that).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because you float the spans. Take a look at css clear: both;

Comment: I personally recommend not using float either. You want to use flex or grid on the container and then justify-content / justify-self.

Comment: Just use paragraphs instead of spans and don't float,,,problem solved

Comment: Float has its uses, for example, to place an image "floating" within an article content, but  it does not seem what you want there. It will turn against you if you use it to design your layout. I agree with @JakeAve, you souldn't use it in this case.

Comment: @E.Zacarias thank you. But I think, I will stick with float. It is easy to use and I am not going to do any more CSS in this project (so, float won't break anything because everything works just fine right now and I am not going to add anything). But I will consider other ways in my future projects. And I am not a front end developer after all (I usually only do the back end). But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to your `<br>` to break the floating, this will result in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and do it .

```html
 <div style="display:flex"> 
   <span style="float:left;padding: 10px 20px 10px 18px;">hey</span>
 <span style="margin-left: auto;
  order: 2; background-color: rgb(104, 109, 117); padding: 10px 20px 10px 18px;">Hi!</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: This answer still has the fundamental vertical spacing problem the poster was asking about...

Comment: @AlexanderNied Can ellaborate ?

Comment: I thought about the alignment and forgot about the new line . clear:both should be good

Answer (score -1):

you can add margin-top:__ (depend on the distance that you want) in the second span

```css
span {
        color: #eeeeee;
        float: right;
        font-size: 120%;
        background-color: #393e46;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 5px 25px;
        padding: 10px 18px 10px 20px;
        margin-top: 2%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    #first{
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 18px;
    }
    #second{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6%; 
    margin-right: 30%;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(104, 109, 117); 
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 18px;
    margin-top:40px;
    }
```

```html
    <span id="first">hey</span>
<br>
<span id="second">Hi!</span>
```